# More pythonic regex parse

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, match

Is there a more pythonic way than doing:

```
 parsedStr=origStr[compiledRegex.match(origStr).start():compiledRegex.match(origStr).end())
```

For exampile assume my original string is "The cat said hi" and my compiled regex is "The.*said" I would pull the text "The cat said"

The above code looks ugly but that's how i've been doing it

Answer (score 1):

Use the *group* method on the match object:

```
>>> import re
>>> origStr = "The cat said hi"
>>> compiledRegex = re.compile('The.*said')
>>> compiledRegex.match(origStr).group()
'The cat said'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
instancesFound = compiledRegex.findall(origStr)
if instancesFound:
    parsedStr = parsedParts[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
search = re.compile(r'^The.*said').search
match = search(input)
if match:
    match = match.group(0)
```

If `input` is "The cat said my name", `match` will be "The cat said".

If `input` is "The cat never mentioned my name", `match` will be `None`.

I really like the fact that Python makes it possible to compile a regular expression and assign the particular method of interest to a variable in one line.